# How to deploy html pages on Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: deployment, websphere, war

I have a small programms which generates daily some static html pages. I would like to publish these files into a Web Application Server

For Jboss I've put all the files in a .war folder and I only have to create a file .dodeploy

The generation of html page is done daily. I have to send the new page every day into the war to complete it.

I need to deploy the war by script not manually does the next command should do the job ?

I would like to do the same for a WebSphere Application server 8.5.5. 
What are the best practices ?

Edit

---

Because websphere requires an ear, I've created one with this architecture :

```
testApp.ear/
   --META-INF/
       -- application.properties
   --testApp.war/
       -- WEB-INF/
             -- web.xml
     index.html
```

The result of the log :

```
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[4/16/18 23:40:10:539 CST] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[4/16/18 23:40:10:805 CST] 00000001 AbstractShell A   WASX7326I: Loaded properties file "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node-3091/properties/wsadmin.properties"
[4/16/18 23:40:11:251 CST] 00000001 ProviderTrack I com.ibm.ffdc.osgi.ProviderTracker AddingService FFDC1007I: FFDC Provider Installed: com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcOnDirProvider@2d9ade48
[4/16/18 23:40:11:331 CST] 00000001 SSLConfig     W   CWPKI0041W: One or more key stores are using the default password.
[4/16/18 23:40:11:337 CST] 00000001 SSLConfigMana I   CWPKI0027I: Disabling default hostname verification for HTTPS URL connections.
[4/16/18 23:40:11:547 CST] 00000001 AdminConfigCl A   WASX7208I: Validation settings in effect now: Level=HIGHEST, Cross-validation=true, Output file=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node-3091/logs/wsadmin.valout
[4/16/18 23:40:11:984 CST] 00000001 ModelMgr      I   WSVR0801I: Initializing all server configuration models
[4/16/18 23:40:13:107 CST] 00000001 WorkSpaceMana A   WKSP0500I: Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled.
[4/16/18 23:40:18:453 CST] 00000001 AbstractShell A   WASX7090I: Executing command: "AdminApp.invoke(AdminApp.installInteractive('testApp.ear'))"
[4/16/18 23:42:53:967 CST] 00000001 AbstractShell E   WASX7120E: Diagnostic information from exception with text "com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7132E: Application install for testApp.ear failed: see previous messages for details.
" follows:

 com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7132E: Application install for testApp.ear failed: see previous messages for details.
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.setAndThrowScriptingException(AbstractShell.java:1878)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminAppClient.invokeMBeanInstall(AdminAppClient.java:5819)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminAppClient.commonInstall(AdminAppClient.java:2922)
...
```

Comment: Is this "Traditional" WebSphere, rather than "Liberty Profile" WebSphere? I think you're asking about having a directory that automatically picks up files as they change over time?

Comment: it's a traditional WebSphere

Comment: Some new files are created over the time, and I need an EAR or WAR that can be built over the time.

Answer (score 0):

The same WAR ought to work just fine, you'll just have to deploy it to WebSphere. This is as simple as clicking next-next-next in the admin console or running a brief wsadmin script.

If you're extremely new but don't have access to the web-based admin console, you can even interactively install on the command line:

Invoke wsadmin then type:

```
AdminApp.installInteractive('/tmp/myapp.war)
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html

Comment: In my war folder I have WEB-INF with web.xml but the tool prompts that my Archive is not a valid EAR file beauce the deployment descriptor can not be found (case snetivie) : META-INF/application.xml 

I have packed everything in an EAR but at the end of the tool I have the message : "Application install for myapp.ear failed: see previous messages for details" but no error message in the log...